# MIPS assembly language la offset

Tags: mips

Let's say I have an array

```
ar .space 15
```

(each element of the array ar is a char, 4 bytes)
so when I execute:

```
la $r0, ar 
add $r0,$r0,1
lb $r1, 8($r0)
```

does the second line add 4 bytes and pointing to second element or ar? does the third line offset second element's address by 8 bytes, so now it's pointing to 4th element of ar?

Thank you

Comment: Normally a char is 1 byte, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

`Ar` does not really have "elements", it's just a space of 15 bytes. What's inside is solely determined by how you use it.

If it is a list of chars (1 byte!), the second instruction will increase the address with 1, thus pointing to the second character. The third instruction's address will point to the ninth character (providing the second address is executed).

If it is a list of words (4 bytes), the second address will generate an address inside a word, thus providing invalid data. If that's the case, the address should be increased with 4, independent if you use the method of the second or third instruction. Furthermore, you should `lw` instead of `lb` in that case.